# Black bar behind status bar with background image iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, swrevealviewcontroller

When I click on the menu icon on the home screen, the side menu displays but there is a black box behind the status bar. The background image used is sized correctly and when I display the side menu as the first view controller, this problem does not occur.

I have checked through the SWReveal tag on SO, and the issues tab on github for a solution.

A video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ek6yp7z8re2nk0z/sidemenuerror.mov

Please let me know if you require additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` on the hidden menu view controller to either `UIRectEdgeAll`, or at least include `UIRectEdgeTop`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the black bar behind status bar is navigation bar.

write this code to hide navigation bar.

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];